# 2 JavaScript events triggered sequentially - 2nd one ignored

Tags: javascript, triggers, onclick, onchange

I have an input text box and a button on a page.
have an onchange event on the text box and an onclick on the button. Each event triggers a totally separate unrelated method.

The problem is as follows:
if the user makes changes to the text box, then right away goes to click on the button - the onchange is triggered but I lose the onclick. 
can I avoid this? I need both events to happen. 
Thanks

Updated:
I tried a very simple test locally:

```
<input type="text" onchange="alert1();"/>
<input type="button" onclick="alert2();"/>
```

where the js is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alert1()
{
alert("1");
}
function alert2()
{
alert("2");
}
</script>
```

changing the text and right away clicking on the button only triggers the first event. Is there a way to force the second event to happen?

Comment: Show us some code if you want us to point the bug.

Comment: the code won't help, I think that it is because the onchange call ajax to refresh a specific field. is there a way to catch the click before the ajax is called? can I check in my JS code if any other events were triggered?

Comment: Without the code, it's hard to say. This simple demo works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/MkbDw/ I get both no matter what. The devil is usually in the details.

Comment: Once you launched the ajax query to the server, you can't take it back. Supposing your server is slow to answer, you can stop handling the answer but I repeat : it's hard to answer your question which is much too vague.

Comment: @NinaNa: It is not really specific, seemingly there is something that you did that prevents the real handler to be called, or the handler only looks as if it was not called.

Comment: ok thanks to all i will research it further... @destroy you are right but it's a little complicated to provide code that will help you or me :)

Comment: I have actually run across this before, but it's been a while and I can't recall the situation or the resolution. If you're not, you should be using some `console.log()` calls in your `onchange` and `onclick` handlers to determine *where things stop* and if the `onclick` *is in fact running* and possibly being overrun by the response and callback handler for your Ajax call. And make sure you're not getting an error (or running the Ajax asynchronously).

Comment: I added some code to clarify my question, any ideas?

Comment: I've got a similar problem, and Asad's answer got me on the track. A click goes unregistered because an onchange event creates a new line, causing the clicked area to scroll away from the pointer before I release the button. Without the mouseup event, the browser does not register the click. (But if I move the pointer to the area's new position and then release the button, the click is registered.) So check your assumptions again :)

Answer (score 0):

An `alert` (along with other modal dialogs) is a bit of a special case, since it suspends execution of the remainder of the script until the user clicks OK. This is why your second handler falls through the cracks.

If you did something like `document.write('foo')` in your handlers instead, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: i changed the innerHTML of an element and still only responding to one event. is this a known issue? should it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function showAlert1() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("ONE") }, 250);
}

function showAlert2() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("TWO") }, 250);
}​
```

It buffers the execution of each function so that the button's onclick can be triggered.